# nodemon - restarting due to changes... never restarts

Tags: node.js, express, nodemon

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZCuF.png)

I tried a lot of things from the internet, nothing works. Whenever I save/change the code the server doesn't restart. Please help.

Comment: try to replace this script in package.json file
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },

Comment: Post more details, better check their GitHub issue section.

Comment: Unfortunately I have searched in many places for a solution and I haven't found any. What worked for me was a complete wipe of the computer and I installed the nodemon globally. It eventually worked, sorry for the late answer.